# How to show/prove, using an arbitrary point, if a set is Open/Closed using their definitions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Lets say $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ is a set, and we want to determine the following:

1. Check/Prove if $S$ is an open set.

To do this, note that:

$S$ is open $\iff$ $$\forall p\in S: p\in \text{Int}(S)$$

$$\forall p\in S: \exists \varepsilon >0 : B(p,\varepsilon)\subseteq S$$

In order to find if $S$ is open, using these definitions, I'm not sure how.

Lets say, for example: $S=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2: 1<x_1<2, -1<x_2<2 \right\}$, where $x=(x_1,x_2)$

Then, it is clear that $S$ is an open rectangle, but *how* do I prove it, using the definitions mentioned?? You may find some $\varepsilon$ for any particular choice $p$, yet how do we find the $\varepsilon(p)$ for some arbitrary $p$?

Of course, if we choose, lets say, $(p_k)=\left(2-\frac{1}{k}, 2-\frac{1}{k}\right)$, then $(p_k)\in S$ and $(p_{k})\to p=(2,2)$ but $\forall k: p_k \neq p$, So $p$ is an accumulation point thats not in $S$. In fact, all sequences that converge to either of these points $(p_{1,k})\to \{1,2\},(p_{2,k})\to\{-1,2\}$ that satisfy those initial conditions, are all accumulation points not in $S$

It turns out that $$\bar{S}=S\cup \{(1,b),(2,b),(a,-1),(a,2),  1<a<2, -1<b<2\}$$

$$\implies \partial S = \{(1,b),(2,b),(a,-1),(a,2), 1<a<2, -1<b<2\}$$

And by one definition of boundary, we get that:

$$\partial S = \bar{S}-\text{Int}(S) \implies \text{Int}(S)=\bar{S}-\partial S$$

$$\implies S= \text{Int}(S)\implies S \text{ is open}$$

But this is not an *actual* proof that $S$ is open, is it? This is more of an intuitive approach, using stuff like closure and the boundary, yet I do not see how one would prove the openness of any given set $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$

In a similar sense:

2. Check/Prove if $S$ is closed ($S=\bar{S}$).

I'd say this is easier, since the accumulation points are easier to compute, but how would one prove that an arbitrary $p$ is an accumulation point of $S$ points *without* choosing any particular $p$? That is, choosing an arbitrary $p$ and then show, or check, immediately if it is an accumulation point of $S$.

$p$ is an accumulation point of $S \iff$ $$\forall \varepsilon>0: B(p,\varepsilon)\cap S-\{c\}\neq \emptyset $$

$$\exists (a_k)\in S: (a_k)\to p \text{ and }\forall k: a_k\neq p$$

Also, is it easier to show that $S^{c}$ is closed, rather than checking if $S$ is open? ($S$ is open $\iff S^{c}$ is closed, the complement of $S$)

Thanks to anyone! I really dont have anyone else to ask, as I'm currently studying with a book.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. I would suggest editing your post to only ask your first question, as we have a "one question per post" policy here.

Comment: For your first question, I would suggest drawing the open rectangle on a piece of paper and marking a point $p=(a,b)$ inside the rectangle. You need to find a radius $r>0$ such that the open disk centred at $p$ with radius $r$ is wholly contained inside the rectangle. This means that we need $r$ to be less than or equal to $|2-a|$, for otherwise the disk would stick out of the right edge of the rectangle. Now try doing something similar for the other three edges.

Comment: The work required to show openness will vary quite a lot from problem to problem, but as you learn more topology you will pick up some methods which will address certain classes of problems. Since you don't have those tools yet, you should do it directly from the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you're saying is valid, but you may be overthinking a bit.

> You may find some $\varepsilon$ for any particular choice $p$, yet how do we find the $\varepsilon (p)$ for some arbitrary $p$?

Let's take your open rectangle $A = (1, 2) \times (-1, 2)$ as an example. Let's take an arbitrary point $x_1 \times x_2 \in A$; it follows that $x_1 \in (1, 2)$ and $x_2 \in (-1, 2)$. Consider $B = B_d (x_1 \times x_2, \varepsilon)$, where $\varepsilon = \min \{ x_1 - 1, 2 - x_1, x_2 + 1, 2 - x_2 \}$, where $d$ is taken to be the Euclidean metric. The intuition here is to create a ball neighborhood that will remain inside of the rectangle. You should be able to convince yourself that $B \subseteq A$. Since $x_1 \times x_2$ was arbitrary, this is all we need to show that $A$ is open.

You are correct that if a set $U$ is open, that it is equal to its interior, $U = \text{Int} U$. Since the interior of any set is a subset of the set, it is equivalent to show that $U \subseteq \text{Int} U$. That is actually exactly what we have done above.

While you could go the route of computing the closure and boundary and taking the difference to find the interior ($\text{Int} A = \text{Cl} A - \text{Bd} A$), this is a lot more work than finding neighborhoods of points in $A$.

For similar reasons, to show that a set $C$ is closed, you can just show that its complement is open: start with an arbitrary point in $X - C$ and find a neighborhood of that point that is contained in $X - C$; i.e. a neighborhood of the point that does not intersect $C$. For general situations, this seems a lot easier than finding the set of all limit points, then proving that each is contained in $C$.